# Page curl effect for webviews in Android

Tags: android, webview, page-curl

I'm working on a project where i need to change between different Webviews on swipe. I want to apply a page curl animation to the webviews on each swipe, i.e., when we swipe on a webview it should get curled and the next webview should be displayed. Can anyone please help me regarding this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you got solution for this? if so please post it since i too had problem..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (asfaik). There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051744/how-to-do-curl-effect-on-html-pages-instead-of-image-in-android), where they suggest javascript but it only seems to work for iOS. That said you could try taking an image of the screen and putting it as an overlay of the webview and then use page curl on the image.