# how to do curl effect on html pages instead of image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

This is the link I have taken as a sample for doing curl effect on android but it is having image flip as i want html page to have that curl effect as we are doing on image. How to do that just give me the idea.

I also gone through http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

same thing i want with html page instead of image , onclick i want html page in curl effect if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something in the html page or the WebView itself ? 
 
For the html page, you can use javascript, something like http://www.turnjs.com/ 
I don't know if it's possible to curl a WebView. I'd say no.

Comment: What i want actually the same effect on webview when I am going to click anywhere it should go to the next page with curl effect in the webview.

Comment: What i want actually the same effect on webview when I am going to click anywhere it should go to the next page with curl effect in the webview.The link you have given which will work on ipad and iphone , it doesnot work on android.